# How to keep user logged in django

Tags: python, django, django-tables2, django-filters

I made my login in the application. Then I go to the screen that list all the users in my database. When I select an especified user I lost my user that is logged. So, how can I keep my user in all the application?

My views.py that list all the users. In this time, the url shows my user (http://localhost:8000/os/acesso/consultausuario/9)

```
def acesso_consultausuario(request, id=None):

    instance = get_object_or_404(usuario, id=id)

    queryset = usuario.objects.all().order_by('dat_criacao_usuario')
    instancia_usuario_filter = usuariofilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)

    table = usuariotable(instancia_usuario_filter.qs)

    RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 25}).configure(table)

    paginator = Paginator(instancia_usuario_filter.qs, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        response = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # if page is not an integer, deliver first page
        response = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # if page is out of range, deliver last pages of results
        response = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

     context = {
        "instance": instance,
        "filter": instancia_usuario_filter,
        "response": response,
        "table": table,
    }
    return render(request, 'consulta/consulta_usuario.html', context)


# Show an especified user that I selected before.
def acesso_consultausuariodetalhe(request, id=None):

    # Instância do usuário que foi selecionado na consulta
    instance = get_object_or_404(usuario, id=id)

    form = statususuarioForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():  # All validation rules pass

        instance_status = form.save(commit=False)
        var_status = form.cleaned_data['statususuario']
        instance_status = statususuario.objects.get(desc_statususuario=var_status)


        # Salva o status atual na tabela logstatususuario
        instance_log = logstatususuario.objects.create(usuario = instance,
                                                        statususuario = instance_status)
        instance_log.save()

        # Seleciona o grupo de acesso
        #var_grupo = form.cleaned_data['grupo']
        #instance_grupo = grupo.objects.get(desc_grupo=var_grupo)

        # Atualiza o usuário com o novo status
        instance.statususuario = instance_status
        #instance.grupo = instance_grupo
        instance.save()

    context = {
        "instance": instance,
        "form": form,
    }

    return render(request, 'consultadetalhe/consulta_usuariodetalhe.html', context)
```

My filters.py

```
    class usuariofilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

        dat_criacao_usuario = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()

        class Meta:
            model = usuario
            fields = ['id', 'dat_criacao_usuario', 'nom_usuario', 'empresa', 'grupo', 'statususuario']

My tables.py

    class usuariotable(tables.Table):

        id = tables.Column(verbose_name='ID', attrs={"td": {"align": "left"}})
        dat_criacao_usuario = tables.Column(verbose_name='Data Cadastro'
                                    ,attrs={"td": {"align": "left"}})
        nom_usuario = tables.Column(verbose_name='Nome'
                                      ,attrs={"td": {"align": "left"}})
        empresa = tables.Column(verbose_name='Empresa'
                                      ,attrs={"td": {"align": "left"}})
        grupo = tables.Column(verbose_name='Grupo'
                                      ,attrs={"td": {"align": "left"}})
        statususuario = tables.Column(verbose_name='Status'
                                      ,attrs={"td": {"align": "left"}})
        ver = tables.TemplateColumn('<a href={% url "acesso_consultausuariodetalhe" record.id %} style="color:#e26c2c">Ver</a>',
                                    verbose_name = '', )


        def __init__(self, *args, vb_statusservico="",**kwargs):  #will get the c1_name from where the the class will be called.
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        class Meta:
            model = usuario
            empty_text = ('No results ...')
            fields = (
                        'id',
                        'dat_criacao_usuario',
                        'nom_usuario',
                        'empresa',
                        'grupo',
                        'statususuario',
                        'ver'
                      )

        def render_id(self, record):
            return record.id
```

Comment: You do know that your `localhost` is local right?

Answer (score 7):

For login a user, you ca use following code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

When a user logs in, the user’s ID and the backend that was used for authentication are saved in the user’s session

Now for access logged user, you can just use **request.user**

ref: [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/)

Comment: I did that, but there is an error in login(request, user): 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @Patricia You probabely have login wrongly imported, or defined a local "login" variable

Answer (score 1):

In your views.py you can access your logged user like this:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser

    def acesso_consultausuario(request):
        my_user = request.user
        #If you want to know if the user is logged in
        is_user_logged = my_user.is_authenticated
```

By the way, I am also a Spanish speaker but it is a good practice to code everything in English so you can share and get feedback with the world (even variable names).
Hope this helps!